# Get Python variable using Grunt

Tags: javascript, python, gruntjs

### 1. Summary

I don't find, how I can get Python variable, use Grunt.

What I need to learn, that solve this task?

---

### 2. Details

I build site use [**Pelican**](https://blog.getpelican.com/) and [**Grunt**](https://gruntjs.com/). I use the same variables:

1. In Python format in `pelicanconf.py` for Pelican
2. In JavaScript format in `Gruntfile.coffee` for Grunt

I want that variables not to be duplicated and contains only in `pelicanconf.py`.

---

### 3. Example

Part of `pelicanconf.py`:

```python
SASHAVARIABLE = 'sashavalue'
```

Part of `Gruntfile.coffee` (I use [**template mechanism**](https://quickleft.com/blog/grunt-js-tips-tricks/)):

```coffee
variables:
    sashavariable: "sashavalue"

exampleplugin:
    exampletask: "<%= variables.sashavariable %>"
```

I want to get value of `SASHAVARIABLE` variable in `pelicanconf.py` via Grunt.

At the time, if I change value of `SASHAVARIABLE`, I need to change value in `Gruntfile.coffee` too. This is a duplicate work.

---

### 4. Not helped

1. I try search queries in Google as [**`(grunt OR javascript) (get OR parse OR scrape) python variable`**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%28grunt+OR+javascript%29+%28get+OR+parse+OR+scrape%29+python+variable&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) → I don't find answer to my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly reading/running Python in JavaScript isn't really something that is easily done.

You could load the Python value as a string and manually parse it. However, I would highly recommend avoid doing this, as it either requires you to have a really simply Python file, or a really complicated string parser.

Instead, I'd recommend picking a format that can easily be read by both. `JSON` is always a good choice when dealling with JavaScript and is can be read in natively:

```
const config = require('./path/to/config.json')
```

and there are parsers for basically every language ([for Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)).

Another common choice would be YAML, though you'll need a third-party library for it in Javascript.

Comment: A small note: [**Grunt support YAML scraping without third-party libraries**](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.readyaml). Thanks!