# Variables from function to current file

Tags: python, python-3.x

### 1. Summary

I can't find, how I can add variables from YAML files to Python files without duplicates.

---

### 2. Purpose

I use [**Pelican — static sites generator**](https://blog.getpelican.com/). [**It use `.py` files for configuration**](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/settings.html#settings). Problems:

1. [**I can't reuse variables from `.py` for JavaScript**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49901700/5951529)
2. [**`import *` antipattern**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2360808/5951529), that use even in [**official Pelican blog**](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-blog/blob/01da56838742e19b1b20955f4c484096cb53d765/publishconf.py#L6)

I try move configuration to YAML files → I get problem of this question.

---

### 3. MCVE

#### 3.1. Files

- [**Live demo on Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/KiragetvariablesfrommultipleYAMLfileswithduplicates)
- `main.py`:

```python
"""First Python file."""
# [INFO] Using ruamel.yaml — superset of PyYAML:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922434/5951529
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

SETTINGS_FILES = ["kira.yaml", "kristina.yaml"]

for setting_file in SETTINGS_FILES:
    VARIABLES = yaml.safe_load(open(setting_file))
    # [INFO] Convert Python dictionary to variables:
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059129/5951529
    locals().update(VARIABLES)

# [INFO] View all variables:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/633134/5951529
print(dir())
```

- `publishconf.py`:

```python
"""Second Python file."""
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

# [NOTE] Another value in list
SETTINGS_FILES = ["kira.yaml", "katya.yaml"]

for setting_file in SETTINGS_FILES:
    VARIABLES = yaml.load(open(setting_file))
    locals().update(VARIABLES)


print(dir())
```

- `kira.yaml`:

```yaml
DECISION: Saint Petersburg
```

- `kristina.yaml`:

```yaml
SPAIN: Marbella
```

- `katya.yaml`:

```yaml
BURIED: Novoshakhtinsk
```

#### 3.2. Expected behavior

- `DECISION` and `SPAIN` variables in `main.py`:

```python
$ python main.py
['DECISION', 'SETTINGS_FILES', 'SPAIN', 'VARIABLES', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__warningregistry__', 'setting_file', 'yaml']
```

- `DECISION` and `BURIED` variables in `publishconf.py`:

```python
$ python publishconf.py
['BURIED', 'DECISION', 'SETTINGS_FILES', 'VARIABLES', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__warningregistry__', 'setting_file', 'yaml']
```

#### 3.3. Problem

Duplicate loop in `main.py` and `publishconf.py`:

```python
for setting_file in SETTINGS_FILES:
    VARIABLES = yaml.load(open(setting_file))
    locals().update(VARIABLES)
```

Can I not use duplicates?

---

### 4. Not helped

#### 4.1. Configuration file

- [**Live demo on Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/Kira-get-variables-from-multiple-YAML-files-N-config-func)
- `config.py`:

```python
"""Config Python file."""
# [INFO] Using ruamel.yaml — superset of PyYAML:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922434/5951529
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

MAIN_CONFIG = ["kira.yaml", "kristina.yaml"]

PUBLISHCONF_CONFIG = ["kira.yaml", "katya.yaml"]


def kirafunction(pelicanplugins):
    """Function for both Python files."""
    for setting_file in pelicanplugins:
        # [INFO] Convert Python dictionary to variables:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059129/5951529
        variables = yaml.safe_load(open(setting_file))
        globals().update(variables)


def main_function():
    """For main.py."""
    kirafunction(MAIN_CONFIG)


def publishconf_function():
    """For publishconf.py."""
    kirafunction(PUBLISHCONF_CONFIG)
```

- `main.py`:

```python
"""First Python file."""
import sys

from config import main_function

sys.path.append(".")


main_function()

# [INFO] View all variables:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/633134/5951529
print(dir())
```

- `publishconf.py`:

```python
"""Second Python file."""
import sys

from config import publishconf_function

sys.path.append(".")


publishconf_function()

print(dir())
```

Variables from `main_function` and `publishconf_function` doesn't share across files:

```python
$ python main.py
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'main_function', 'signal', 'sys']
```

#### 4.2. Another attempts

1. Wrap loop to function as in this example:

   ```python
   def kirafunction():
       """Docstring."""
       for setting_file in SETTINGS_FILES:
           VARIABLES = yaml.safe_load(open(setting_file))
           locals().update(VARIABLES)


   kirafunction()
   ```
2. [**Using `global` keyword**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10588342/5951529)
3. “[**I think editing `locals()` like that is generally a bad idea. If you think `globals()` is a better alternative, think it twice!**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059129/5951529)”
4. [**Search**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpkHg.png) in [**Stack Overflow questions**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHcTw.png)

Comment: In general, to avoid duplicates in python we use sets, so maybe you could try to implement some in your code

Comment: Why are you using `locals()` or `globals()` at all? Save everything to variables.

Comment: `locals().update(VARIABLES)` is totally wrong. That is not going to work in a function, and is explicitly warned against in the documentation. Simply use the dictionary. You don't need variables, *use the container*.

Comment: @AdrianKrupa, `type: answer`. I try [**as in this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059129/5951529). Thanks.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, `type: reply`. I've update my question. Look at 2 item. Thanks.

Comment: What is your point? You don't need variables, just use the dictionary you get back from the config.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, `type: reply`. `You don't need variables, just use the dictionary you get back from the config.` — look at item 2 of my question and [**Pelican configuration example**](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/settings.html#example-settings). If I really don't need variables, can you write example, what can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid any update to what `locals` returns, because documentation explicitely states:

> Note
>   The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

The globals function is a dictionnary simply containing the attributes of a module, and the mapping returned by `globals` is indeed writable.

So if this exists in one Python source:

```
def kirafunction(map,settings):
  # [NOTE] Another value in list
  for setting_file in settings:
    VARIABLES = yaml.load(open(setting_file))
    map.update(VARIABLES)
```

This can be used from any other Python source after importing the above function:

```
kirafunction(globals(), settings)
```

and will import the variables in the globals dictionnary of the calling module. And will be highly non-pythonic...

A slightly more Pythonic way, would be to dedicate one Python module to hold both the code loading the yaml files **and** the new variables:

loader.py:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

SETTINGS_FILES = ["kira.yaml", "kristina.yaml"]

for setting_file in SETTINGS_FILES:
    VARIABLES = yaml.safe_load(open(setting_file))
    # [INFO] Convert Python dictionary to variables:
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059129/5951529
    globals().update(VARIABLES)
```

Then from any other Python module you can use:

```
...
import loader      # assuming that it is in sys.path...
...
print(loader.DECISION)
print(dir(loader))
```

But it is still uncommon and would require comments to explain the rationale for it.

---

After reading the Pelican config example from you comment, I assume that what you need is a way to import in different scripts a bunch of variables declared in yaml files. In that case I would put the code loading the variables in one module, and update the `globals()` dictionnary in the other modules:

loader.py:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

MAIN_CONFIG = ["kira.yaml", "kristina.yaml"]

PUBLISHCONF_CONFIG = ["kira.yaml", "katya.yaml"]


def kirafunction(pelicanplugins):
    """Function for both Python files."""
    variables = {}
    for setting_file in pelicanplugins:
        # [INFO] Convert Python dictionary to variables:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059129/5951529
        variables.update(yaml.safe_load(open(setting_file)))
    return variables
```

Then for example in `publishconf.py` you would use:

```
from loader import kirafunction, PUBLISHCONF_CONFIG as pelican_config

# other Python code...

# import variables from the yaml files defined in PUBLISHCONF_CONFIG
#  because Pelican expects them as plain Python module variables
globals().update(kirafunction(pelican_config))
```

Again, updating `globals()` is probably appropriate in this use case, but is generally frowned upon, hence the comment.

Comment: `But it is still uncommon and would require comments to explain the rationale for it.` — look at [**my comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55099110#comment96942881_55099529) for another answer. Thanks.

Comment: Serge Ballesta, `type: need clarification`. **1.** Can you show full another Python module code? Look at 4.1. item of my question for details. // **2.** Is `globals()` from your answer a good practice? Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных: 1. I am sorry, by I cannot really understand what you are trying to achieve... 2. Definitely not, except when strictly required. What I mean here is that dynamic creation of variables is generally deemed as a code smell, and you should prefere a simple mapping (a dict or dict sub class) if you can use it. But I do not use or know Pelican, so I cannot know whether that kind of solution is appropriate, or whether you are experimenting a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Serge Ballesta, // **1.** `type: clarification`. Can you add to your example full `main.py` or `publishconf.py`? // **2.** `type: reply`. [**Example Pelican configuration**](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/settings.html#example-settings). I try to move this configuration to YAML files by reasons from item 2 of my question. // Please, tell me, if I need to say some more information. Thanks.